# WordPress is giving me 404 page not found for all pages except the homepage

Tags: wordpress

All of a sudden I go to my WordPress website and all the pages give me a 404 page not found page. I'm assuming the problem lies with the permalink structure, which I could swear I did not touch. The permalink setting is on "month and name."

I've researched similar instances of this problem online and a lot of it has to do with the `.htaccess` file? I tried finding, but I can't. Perhaps it got deleted somehow? Where is it supposed to be located.

Any suggestions will be helpful

and of course I can see hidden files.

Comment: Suggest you ask this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: you can change permalink from db level also :http://sforsuresh.in/wordpress-update-permalink-database

Answer (score 103, accepted):

.htaccess is a hidden file, so you must set all files as visible in your ftp.

I suggest you return your permalink structure to default ( ?p=ID ) so you ensure that .htaccess is the problem.

After that, you could simply set "month and name" structure again, and see if it works.

PS: Have you upgraded to 3.1? I've seen some people with plugin issues in this case.

Comment: yes i've shown hidden files. I've switched back and forth from default to perma and it works in default. Also, does wordpress update itself or something? I notice that when i logon I have a new admin task bar on my website, which I didnt have before. I dont know how it got there.

Comment: someone mistakenly updated to 3.1, so it conflicted with a plugin

Comment: Missing `.htaccess` also could lead to this issue, whatever you correct the permalink, so check that first, not hidden or missing

Comment: Simply login to the WordPress admin and save the parmalinks again. This wil generate a .htaccess file or update the existing one.

Comment: I have tried using admin and manually update .htaccess file but still same issue. Disable Plugin as well but not fix permalink issue.

Comment: Default wasn't an option but Plain was - and that worked. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! So, I kinda doubt it will be this easy for most, but switching the permalink structure to (?p=ID) and then back to Post name (my original setting) worked for me!

Comment: this solution worked for me, My htaccess file was hidden

Comment: for me permalink was working, then tried with month and name but not working, so updated .htacess but still not working... finally I found `sudo a2enmod rewrite ` and restart my apache, its started working

Answer (score 89):

Basically the .htaccess file should exists and the httpd.conf should be correct.

In my case, I changed the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf in section:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

Line changed is:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

And restart the web server with

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: thanks, that helped. In my case the AllowOverride setting was missing.

Comment: This fixed it for me too. I'm using vagrant scotchbox for what it's worth.

Comment: This is almost always the problem. Should be top answer.

Comment: This corrected the issue for me- Should be the accepted answer

Comment: This was helpful for me, This should be on # 1

Answer (score 57):

Fixing that problem is very simple if you was using permalinks other than the `default` such as `Day and name`, `Month and name`, `Numeric`, `Post name` or `Custom Structure`, you only need to

Login to your admin area: `Settings > Permalinks` which should be : `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`

**Choose `Default` permalink setting**, then save changes

Then you can **return it again to your other previous permalink choice** or **keep it as `default` as yo wish**

Note that this problem can happen when you move your site from a domain or location to another one.

Comment: This somewhat helped me, I had some database errors and afterwards all my pages were 404. Switching the permalink option to another option (such as plain) then back to the default option fixed all my links!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Perfect answer +100

Comment: How can I revert back to **Default** permalink setting when even `mysite.com/wp-admin` isn't working?

Comment: Perfect answer +10086

Comment: When I go to the link I get "Rewrite rules for VIP sites should be flushed via VIP => Rewrite rules."

Comment: I didn't even have to click save after choosing `Default`. I changed back to my custom structure right away and saved. If this occurs again I would even try going to the permalink setting page and just click save to see if it works.

Comment: WARNING for custom structure. If you use custom structure, note down the structure because it will disappear right after you click other options.

Answer (score 40):

If the default behavior (`example.com/?p=42`) is working, you should:

- Change to your preferred permalink style: `Admin: Settings > Permalinks`, and click Save. Sometime it fixes the issue. If it didn't:
- Verify that the file `/path/to/wordpress/.htaccess` has been changed and now includes the line `RewriteEngine On`. If it doesn't include the line, it's a Wordpress permissions issue.
- Verify that the 'rewrite' module is loaded: create a PHP file with

  ```
  <?php
    phpinfo()
  ?>
  ```

  in it, open it in the browser and search for `mod_rewrite`. It should be in the 'Loaded Modules' section.
  If it's not, enable it - Look at your apache default `index.html` file for details - in Ubuntu, you do it with the helper `a2enmod`.
- Verify that apache server is looking at the `.htaccess` file. open `httpd.conf` - or it's Ubuntu's alternative, `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. In it, You should have something like

  ```
  <Directory /path/to/wordpress>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ```
- After making these changes, don't forget to restart your apache server. `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 32):

**IF all this dont work, your .htaccess is correct, and permalinks trick didnt work, you may have not enabled your apache2 rewite mod**.

I ran this and my issue was solved:

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Search for `mod_rewrite` in `phpinfo();` page to check if you have enabled. It is in `Loaded Modules` of `apache2`

Comment: Thank you! I had to change AllowOverride to All in apache2.conf AND run your code to enable rewrite.

Answer (score 10):

Within the WordPress admin interface do the following:

1. Go to admin setting
2. Click on permalink and select post name in radio button.
3. Scroll down and you will see `.htaccess` code here like.

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
4. Copy the code and paste in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Where do I find this? There's nothing like this in permalinks.

Comment: @Boris_yo As far as I know, the rules will show up only if  your `htaccess` file is `not` writable.. if it is wordpress will simply write it itself ...

Comment: This answer is awesome! and won't ever know about it unless using WP in Linux. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

This error is causing due to disabled of rewrite mod in apache httpd.conf document ,just uncomment it and enjoy the seo friendly permalinks

Answer (score 4):

- Check that the directory on .htaccess are the correct
- Check the fields "siteurl" and "home" are the correct

Comment: For me, the home was the problem. I fix it and all back to work. Obrithankyou José Carlos.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem and solved it by checking the error.log of our virtual host. We found the following message:

> AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off,
>   so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar
>   ability to circumvent directory restrictions :
>   /srv/www/htdocs/wp-intranet/

The solution was to set `Options All` and `AllowOverride All` in our virtual host config.

Answer (score 3):

If you have FTP access to your account:

First, login to your wp-admin and go to Settings > Permalinks

You should see something at the bottom that says:

"If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all."

If this is true do the following:

1. Go into preferences for your FTP client and make sure hidden files are displayed (varies depending on your FTP client) - If you don't do this you won't be able to find your htaccess file
2. Go to the folder that your wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes directories are located. Check for .htaccess file. If it exists skip to step 4
3. If it does not exist, create a new blank file in your FTP program called .htaccess
4. Change the CHMOD for your .htaccess file to 666 (your preference on how you want to do this)
5. Go back to your Permalinks page and edit the link structure you want. Problem should be solved!
6. Make sure to change the chmod of the htaccess file back to 644 after you are done.

Just had the same problem and it seemed to fix it instantly! Good luck!

Comment: "mod_rewrite" this was the problem, I forgot to enable it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time this issue is fixed by simply visiting the **Settings -> Permalink** page in the WordPress admin and click Save (as several other answers already pointed out). When this page is accessed, WordPress rewrites the directives in the `.htaccess` file which magically fixes the issue. The issue often happens after moving a site (the site breaks because the `.htaccess` gets left behind or the settings need to be updated).

If WordPress doesn't have the right permissions to write the `.htaccess` file, a notice will appear at the top of the page and further instructions at the bottom when the settings are saved. In this case you need to edit the `.htaccess` file yourself or, better, to fix the permissions on that file. The file is at the root of the WordPress installation. `cd` into the directory and `sudo chmod 644 .htaccess`. You might also want to check if the file belongs to the right group and change that is needed with `chown`. Ask your hosting provider if you don't know how to do that.

If you are on shared hosting that's probably all you can do. If you still have the issue you might want to talk to you hosting provider's support. Otherwise, make sure the use of `.htaccess` files is enabled on the server, as @georgeos already suggested. Note that `httpd.conf` is not always used ([Ubuntu indicates it is deprecated](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) but [the official Apache docs still says it is often the main configuration file](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html)). `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` seem to be the most common places for this file. Find the block for the public folder, usually `<Directory /var/www/>` and make sure that the `AllowOverride` directive is set to `All`. If it is set to `None`, your `.htaccess` file is simply ignored by the server.

Answer (score 2):

I installed mod_rewrite to fix the issue. Below link provides an installation guide:- 
http://www.iasptk.com/enable-apache-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Answer (score 2):

You may have .htaccess disallowed in webhost settings.
Setting to default permalinks would work in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to do any permalink or server config changes, please check you .htaccess file. This mostly is a corrupt or blank .htaccess file issue. Reset the htaccess file to the [default](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Case 1:- Let us think if migrate site from one hosting to another hosting if see this kind of issue.

Solution:- Simply go to old server copy .htaccess file code, then past in new server .htaccess file. 99% it i will works.

Answer (score 1):

If your WordPress installation is in a subfolder (ex. https://www.example.com/subfolder) change this line in your WordPress `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
```

By doing so, you are telling the server to look for WordPress `index.php` in the WordPress folder (ex. https://www.example.com/subfolder) rather than in the  public folder (ex. https://www.example.com).

Answer (score 1):

after 2 long days, 
the solution was to add `options +FollowSymLinks` to the top of my `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your WordPress Dashboard, scroll down to settings, select Permalink,

in custom settings that appear, go to custom structure and replace the text in the text field with

```
/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

and then save changes

Answer (score 1):

This scenario can also be caused by a database version that's out of sync with the WP files installed on server. Nothing else listed here worked for me; I solved it with a manual WP update.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and so I remove the Apache and make it again and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just Navigate to **Settings->Permalink** in your dashboard and then **Save Changes** button in the last.\

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the permalink to 'month and day'of all the posts by ging to setting>permalink.

Now all posts are open and working fine.

Again, I renamed to all posts to its actual permalink. Its again working fine.

This method worked for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

**For nginx users**

Use the following in your conf file for your site (usually `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`)

`location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            }`

This hands off all permalink requests to index.php with a URI string and supplied arguments. Do a `systemctl reload nginx` to see the changes and your non-homepage links should load.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share my two cents. Recently came accross that very same issue installing WordPress `5.9`. Year 2021.

Configuration:

> Platform MAC, Software `XAMPP`, WordPress `5.9`

None of the previous answer did it for me.

The issue was due to the fact that files permissions accross the `XAMPP` folder were set to "Read only".

1. Locate the `XAMPP` folder. (Usually in the Applications folder).
2. Right click `XAMPP` folder.
3. `Get info`.
4. Bottom right unlock button → Follow instructions.
5. `Sharing and permissions` → `Everyone` → `Read & Write`.
6. Bottom left three dots button → `Apply to enclosed items`.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue not so long ago. I had reset my permalink to default or just saved it, updated themes/core to (4.7.4)/plugins, deactivated all plugins, switched to default theme, optimized database, .htaccess is already default, checked file permissions, mod_rewrite is on.

So far nothing works, what works are the posts, new page, the /contact page EXCEPT for old pages.

Basically, the pages/URLs that aren't working are:

```
/breeding
/training
/training/*
/breeding/*
```

Ultimate, I found these files in the root folder:

/breeding.php and /training.php

**I renamed both files and the pages above worked.**