# WordPress internal pages show 404

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I recently migrated a WordPress based website to EC2. The homepage of the site loads fine but the internal pages show a 404. The site runs Ubuntu 16.04, Apache2, PHP 7.0 and MySQL server 5.7. I've installed the site at `/var/www/somesitename`.

I've tried the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182534/wordpress-is-giving-me-404-page-not-found-for-all-pages-except-the-homepage/41928159#41928159) and this worked for another site but surprisingly it does not work with this particular site. Without adding the lines in `/etc/apache2/apach2.conf` mentioned in the above-linked solution, the homepage loads but not the internal pages. If I add those lines, the site tries to load but eventually, I see a `could not connect to the database` error. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I've also tried updating the permalinks from the WordPress dashboard but that did not work. The `rewrite` module is enabled. Also, the site works fine on my notebook in a MAMP environment.

Comment: Go to Settings » Permalinks,  (post_name) and simply click on Save Changes button.

Comment: Tried this. Did not work.

Comment: sudo a2enmod rewrite u check this

Comment: Yep activated that the first thing. It didn't work.

Comment: When you go to an internal page, does it show the right URL? If you can't access the DB, it's not related to permalinks or htaccess...

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/o6kQNAo.png) is what the 404 page looks like. The strange bit is that on my local machine with MAMP it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

can you reset your permalink too from back end Settings -> Permalink -> Post name

Answer (score -1):

How did you migrate the website? Did you set the settings in wp-config.php to be able to connect to the new database?
I mean these fields:

1. `define('DB_NAME', 'insertdbnamehere');`
2. `define('DB_USER', 'insertdbuserhere');`
3. `define('DB_PASSWORD', 'insertpwhere');`
4. `define('DB_HOST', 'inserthostnamehere');`

`wp_config.php` is located in the Wordpress root of your site, in the FTP. Next to the `wp-content`, `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` directories.

Comment: Yes I've populated these. As I said, I can see the homepage.

Comment: I figured this could be it since you get a 'could not connect to the database' error.